# Predicate Logic - Use of Domination Law

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

I have been working on school project for a few days and have encountered this problem on predicate logic, which I can't figure out.
I am given an argument :

H1: p ∧ q ,
H2: p → ¬(q ∧ z),
H3: r → z ,
H4: m ∧ p → r

This should imply ¬m.

This is what I have got:
1. H1 and use Simplification to get p.

2. Take p from step 1 and H2 to get p ∧ (p → ¬(q ∧ z)), then use modus ponens to get ¬(q ∧ z).
3. Use De Morgan's law on ¬(q ∧ z) to get ¬q ∨ ¬z.
4. Take q from H1 to get q ∧ (¬q ∨ ¬z), which can be rewritten as q ∧ (q → ¬z), which can be simplified using modus ponens to ¬z.
5. Take ¬z from 4 and H3 to get ¬z ∧ (r → z). This can be simplified using modus tollens to ¬r.
6. Rewrite H4 using contraposition, arriving at (¬r → ¬(m ∧ p)).
7. Using De Morgan's we can adjust the left side of the argument, arriving at (¬r → (¬m ∨ ¬p)).
8. Combining step 5 and 7 we arrive at ¬r ∧ (¬r → (¬m ∨ ¬p)), which can be simplified using modus ponens to ¬m ∨ ¬p.
9. And now the step I am a little confused about. We assume that H1 is true, hence p must be true, which implies, that its complement, ¬p, must be false. Thus we can restate the result of 8 and get (¬m ∨ false), which logically gives us ¬m.

So, is step 9 correct reasoning? Or am I missing something? I have got really excited about this, and am very keen to get this right. So if there is something wrong, please let me know, I will try to work out some other way.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $A$ and $\neg A\vee B$ entails $B$, by rule of *disjunctive syllogism*

So too $p$ and $\neg p\vee\neg m$ entails $\neg m$.

---

If you prefer, you may use implication equivalence: $\neg p\vee\neg m$ equates to $p\to\neg m$.

Thence $p$ and $p\to\neg m$ entails $\neg m$ by rule of *modus ponens*.

(… as you already did in step 4, where you reasoned that $q$ and $\neg q\vee\neg z$ entails $\neg z$.)